# Ocultar ventana a la hora de imprimir con ProcesStarInfo()

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando imprimir un ticket generado en un archivo .txt pero a la hora que mando a imprimir con ProcesStarInfo() se muestra la ventana del bloc de notas.

Mi sistema operativo es Windows 11, probé con windows 10 y en esta solo imprime sin ejecutarse el bloc de notas

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este detalle en Windows 11?

```
private void PrintTicket(string path)
        {
        
            try {
                var info = new ProcessStartInfo() {
                    Verb = "print",
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    FileName =path,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                };
                Process.Start(info);
                MessageBox.Show("Ticket Generado Correctamente", "Exito!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                
                MessageBox.Show("Hubo un error al imprimir " +ex, "Error!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                throw;
            }
        
        }
```

Windows 11

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Windows 10

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Segun la documentacion de **CreateNoWindow**

- [ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow?view=net-7.0)

> Si la UseShellExecute propiedad es true o las UserName propiedades y
> Password no nullson , se omite el valor de la CreateNoWindow propiedad
> y se crea una nueva ventana.

Entonces prueba asi agregando esta propiedad [UseShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=net-7.0)  de *ProcessStartInfo*

```
UseShellExecute = false;
```

Tu codigo te quedaria asi:

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo() {
                Verb = "print",
                UseShellExecute = false
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                FileName =path,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            };
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia

Comment: Hola, Intenté pero me bota este error  System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

Comment: Creo que el principal detalle es, por que el FileName no es un ejecutable como tal.